# C++ compiler that doesn't put data in .text section

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, assembly, g++, disassembly

I am disassembling my executable with libdisasm.

However, there are many issues from disassembling my executable since there is data and jump tables inbetween and inside of functions.

The .map file generated only lists the addresses of the functions in my executable, but it doesn't list their size so it is constantly disassembling chunks of data that visual studio compiled into the .text section.

Since every call and jump must be fixed when I insert new opcodes into the .text section. Having a incomplete and inaccurate disassembly results in a run time crash when its rebuilt.

Is there a way to:

- Make visual studio only compile code in the .text section
- Have visual studio output a way to track what is code and what is
  data in the .text section

Or is there a compiler that does not put data in .text section?
I have tried g++ and it also appends data to the end of the .text section.

Comment: You can use [#pragma section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa.aspx) to control the section things are put in, if that helps?

Comment: _"The .map file generated only lists the addresses of the functions in my executable, but it doesn't list their size"_ Maybe you should focus on fixing this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I attempted to have it disasseble until a return, but since there can be multiple returns in a function it leaves some code out. I haven't see anything to indicate that the .map file would give you the function size. I've seen in older versions of visual studio you could output the line numbers, but that has been depreciated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit gesundheit

Comment: @JonathanPotter creating a section would only work on my declarations. I need to also disassemble all the functions embedded from the includes that I didn't write. Its good to know that exists though.

Comment: Can you get your hands onto the used linker script? If so you could modify it to make sure you only have code in some section.

Comment: Wouldn't `-ffunction-sections` make GCC put every function in its own section? Of course, the linker merges the whole bunch, but you know from the .o files how big each contribution is.